# What happens when a Swift "if let ... " on a Dictionary key fails?

Tags: swift, dictionary, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I've got a dictionary that's deliberately setup to fail when there's no pre-existing value in it matching a certain criteria.

All other times, this command will work, but for one time. I'm hoping I'm doing this right... that the fail means nothing happens. That I don't need an `else` or any other contingency code.

But is that right?

```
if let myTestKonstant = myDictionary[Int(store.itemID)]{
         // successful assignment code here   
        }

// where I'm hoping a failure to assign falls through to...
```

Comment: Yes, if the key is not found in the dictionary, the code in the braces of the `if` statement simply won't execute, and it will resume after the `if` statement.

Comment: yes @Rob is right and this will prevent crash, if value of that key doesn't exist in dict.

Comment: Consider that your *key* is an optional.

Comment: Thank you @Rob, that's exactly what I was looking to know. CHEERS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely right, the problem is that the conversion to int is also optional. For example, this would crash (or rather, you would get a compiling error):

```
let myDictionary = [3: "3"]
let itemID = "b"
if let myTestKonstant = myDictionary[Int(itemID)] {
    print(myTestKonstant)
}
```

This would be the save way:

```
if let itemKey = Int(itemID), let myTestKonstant = myDictionary[itemKey] {
    print(myTestKonstant)
}
```

**UPDATE**

So it is clearer, I will explain what would happen in different cases:

1. `itemID` can't be converted to an `Int`: This would mean that `itemKey` will be `nil`, hence, the second part would't even be tested and the content of the if wouldn't be executed.
2. `itemID` can be converted to an `Int`, but it is not an existing key: In this case `itemKey` would be set to the `Int` `itemID` gets converted to. Then, the second statement would be tested, but since `itemKey` would not be found as an existing key, `myDictionary[itemKey]` would return `nil` and again, the content of the if would not be executed.
3. `itemID` can be converted to an `Int` that exists as key of the dictionary. Like in the previous case, `itemKey` will be set, and since the key is found, `myTestKonstant` will be filled and the content of the if will be executed, unless the corresponding value of the key is `nil` (like in `[3: nil]`).

Comment: I think this needs a second `if let...` because the `itemKey`, whilst a real `Int`, maybe not be a key in the dictionary.

Comment: If it's not an existing key, myTestKonstant will just be nil and it won't enter the if

Comment: The first `if let...` doesn't check if it's a real key, only that it's possible to turn it into an integer. Sorry, perhaps not enough context. In my Dictionary, no value below 20 is a possible key, nor are any greater numbers not divisible by 10. And the initial state of the itemID is a value less than 20. It's used as sort of switch.

Comment: And the values being passed in the 'itemID` are `TimeIntervals`, and always whole numbers (`Ints`) so the switching mechanism can behave as I want. My query really is stemming from the complete ignorance of not being entirely sure what happens to the failing of an `if let...`

Comment: argh, I was subconsciously seeing the comma `,` as a `;`. What I've learnt, just now, is that it's possible to make an `if let...` into a series of two queries. Is this what's called `chaining`?

Answer (score 2):

When you implicitly unwrap an optional, you check and unwrap its value in a single statement. So you don't need any error handling code

So doing

```
if let definiteString = assumedString {
   print(definiteString)
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if assumedString != nil {
   print(assumedString)
}
```

You can read more about implicitly unwrapped optional [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID334)

Comment: you forgot the assignment to definiteString in the equivalence

Comment: Not really equivalent; the first example will print, for instance `"myString"`, while the second will print `Optional("myString")` as it hasn't been unwrapped yet.